# How does the initial turn-on transient decay into the steady state in a given circuit?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

How does the initial turn-on transient decay into the steady state in a given circuit? For example, in a parallel circuit, how does the voltage over both arms of the parallel circuit equal to that of the battery?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general outline of the process:

The sudden application of a voltage to a circuit means that the circuit in that instant is being driven by a a signal containing a variety of different AC (sinusoid) frequencies whose sum yields a step function (or something arbitrarily close to it) superimposed on a DC component.

If the circuit being driven contains inductances and capacitances, then the impedances of those components will interact with the AC signal components contained within the step function.

Since the sinusoid components of the step function are arranged in such a manner that they exist almost exclusively in the very instant that the step function is imposed on the circuit, they will disappear from the excitation profile very promptly.

This means that the frequency-dependent responses of the circuit to the high-frequency spectrum contained in the step function because of the presence of those capacitances and inductances cannot persist in time because the excitation does not persist in time.

(While this last assertion assumes that the circuit overall contains some resistive components in association with the inductive and capacitive components that would dissipate the current and voltage signals created by those inductances and capacitances, any real-world circuit will have them.)

This means that the overall response of a circuit to the imposition of a step function can be modelled accurately by the sum of a steady-state DC response and an AC component that decays exponentially with time.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding these transients is to think about capacitance and inductance.  The current through a capacitor is governed by $I=C\frac{dV}{dt}$ and the voltage across an inductor is governed by $V=-L\frac{dI}{dt}$.  These rate-dependent terms lead to a smoothly changing current or voltage.

The other key is to understand parasitic capacitance and inductance.  All *real* components have some capacitance and inductance.  For example, they have capacitence with respect to a ground plane, or even just the opposite end of the component.  Likewise, every pair of parallel wires generates some magnetic fields, and thus has inductance.  For the most part, we get to ignore these effects.  The capacitances and inductances are simply so small that the voltages and currents can change faster than we can measure.  We can often treat them as "instantaneous."  However, if you're interested in looking deeper and deeper until you start to see *how*  circuit switches from off to on, you'll eventually reach a timescale where you can see these effects.

In RF transmissions like radio or digital transmissions such as those over Ethernet or PCI-e, these effects are decidedly not ignorable.  In that domain, you spend a great deal of time managing these "impedence" effects.  For example, the graph [below](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180012/pcie-diagnosing-and-improving-an-eye-diagram) is of a clock line being switched on or off, overlayed many times (so you see both directions.. they're trying to make sure the clock timing is right).  In an ideal world, there would be a perfectly discontinuous rise and fall.  In this real world, you can see all sorts of interesting second order effects.

[image: Eye diagram]

If you explore even fancier circuits, you can get into situations where you can't use this lumped transmission line model with discrete inducitors and capacitors.  Then you might actually have to solve Maxwell's equations, or even QM equations to figure out what is going on.  But practically speaking, you won't have to do this in all but the most pathological of situations.

Answer (score -1):

> How does the initial turn-on transient decay into the steady state in a given circuit?

To find this out in general you have to solve the transient behavior of each particular circuit.

> For example, in a parallel circuit, how does the voltage over both arms of the parallel circuit equal to that of the battery?

In this case, KVL applies instantaneously, so there is no transient to worry about. As soon as you connect an (ideal) battery across a load, the voltage across that load is equal to the battery voltage. It doesn't matter whether the load is a parallel circuit, a series circuit, a single two-terminal element, or a huge complicated circuit.

If the battery has internal resistance (all real batteries do) and the load has an appreciable capacitance (not all do), then you'd have to solve for the time required for the battery to charge the parasitic capacitor through its internal resistance to find how the voltage across the load evolves after connecting the battery.